# Moving File From DCM4CHEE to FTP server

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-server, dcm4che

I have a dcm4chee PACS server I want to write a code that can move the files from the dcm4chee server to FTP server in JAVA  I need guidance in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to get data out of a PACS archive is using DICOM Query/Retrieve. Try using the DCM4CHE tools to do so (look at dcmqr for an example). There are other DICOM toolkits as well, but if your PACS is DCM4CHEE, then the DCM4CHE toolkit is probably a good place to start.

Once you have the data, use a toolkit for uploading FTP, perhaps Apache Commons (http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-upload-tutorial-and-example).